# PowerShell v2 Converts Dictionary to Array when returned from a function

Tags: json, function, powershell, powershell-2.0

First off, I am bound to PowerShell v2 because that is what is installed by default on Windows 7. What I want to do works out of the box with PowerShell v4, and, possibly, PowerShell v3.

I want to read a JSON object from a file and use it as an object in my script. PowerShell v2 does not have the ConvertFrom-Json method, so I wrote my own implementation that I want to have the same functionality:

```
function ConvertFrom-Json
{
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$json
    )
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")
    $ser = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    $obj = $ser.DeserializeObject($json)

    Write-Host $obj.GetType()

    return $obj
}
```

I call this function like this:

```
$configObj =  (Get-Content $configFile) -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host $configObj.GetType()
```

The output of this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
System.Object[]
```

And I am not able to interact with $configObj like an object and get it's properties. In fact, I can't figure out how to get any information out of it. When I print the object, the output looks like:

```
AC    Version        Location                                                                                                                                                                                           
---    -------        --------                                                                                                                                                                                           
True   v2.0.50727         C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll                                                                                             

Key   : DownloadURL
Value : https://example.com

Key   : dir
Value :
```

When I expect it to look like:

```
Key                                                                                                          Value                                                                                                       
---                                                                                                          -----                                                                                                       
DownloadURL                                                                                                  https://example.com          
dir
```

Is there a way to work around this and get the same object back from my ConvertFrom-Json method as exists inside my method?

Thanks in advance,

Andy

Comment: `[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")` or `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions`

Comment: Wow, awesome. That fixed it! It didn't even occur to me that LoadWithPartialName was returning a value that got picked up by PowerShell. You are a lifesaver! And quick too!

Comment: @PetSerAl out of curiosity, why did you answer the question with a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result of every statement, with exception for assignment and increment/decrement, considered part of your function return. You does not have to use `return` statement to return something from function. So your function actually return two objects: loaded `Assembly` object from `LoadWithPartialName` method and dictionary from `$obj` variable. When you assign multiple function results to variable, PowerShell have to pack results into array. As you does not actually need `Assembly` object, you can cast result of `LoadWithPartialName` method to `[void]`:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions"‌​)
```

Also `LoadWithPartialName` method is `Obsolete` and you should not use it at all. For loading assembly, you can use `Add-Type` build-in cmdlet:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions
```

As you does not use named blocks in your function, all code considered to be an `end` block, thus you only process last pipeline input in your function. You should use `process` block to process every pipeline input object:

```
process{
    $ser.DeserializeObject($json)
}
```

When statement return collection, than PowerShell enumerate this collection and write each individual collection's item instead of collection as single element. So if your JSON contains array at top level, you function will return array elements instead of array itself, as build-in `ConvertFrom-Json` does. You can use unary array operator to prevent enumeration of returned array:

```
,$ser.DeserializeObject($json)
```

The total:

```
function ConvertFrom-Json {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$json
    )
    begin {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions
        $ser = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    }
    process {
        ,$ser.DeserializeObject($json)
    }
}
```